# Connect BigQuery with Knime

Tags: api, jdbc, google-bigquery, driver, knime

I'm trying to connect the with Knime the BigQuery API to download or make some querys at the Knime console, and I have some problems with the Driver.

I install de simba googlebigquery driver but don't works because I don't know how to complete this (`<protocol>://<host>:<port>/<database_name>`). Can anyone help me if knows how to run the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Install and Configuration Guide that comes with the JDBC driver has an example of a complete connection URL as:

```
jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;P‌​rojectId=MyBigQueryP‌​roject;OAuthType=1
```

The only part you should need to change is replacing `MyBigQueryP‌​roject` with your own project name.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help.
But, when i need to put the username and the password, what credentials I put?

Thanks.